# How to add element and remove element from array through javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
let objArr = [
  { "name" : "mark", "height" : "tall", "hairColor": "black"},
  { "name" : "ben", "height" : "medium", "color": "fair"},
  { "name" : "neil", "height" : "small", "color": "dark"}
];

addmoreObject = {"gender": "male", "age": 33};

const res = objArr.map(({ hairColor, color, addmoreObject ...r }) => r);
console.log("RES", res)
```

I wanted to remove color and hairColor from object and wanted to add more element like gender, age etc. how can I make it in correct manner please guide

```
https://jsfiddle.net/v0yLu8m2/
```

Comment: `addmoreObject ...r` should be `addmoreObject, ...r`; there’s a comma missing. Although, `addmoreObject` won’t refer to `gender` and `age`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I assume you don't want to add the same gender and age to all entries, so do you want to update just a single object? And do you want to remove properties from just the object you are adding properties to, or from all objects?

Comment: `addmoreObject` is not declared, too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close:

```js
// Change
const res = objArr.map(({ hairColor, color, addmoreObject ...r }) => r);

// To
const res = objArr.map(({ hairColor, color, ...rest }) => {
  return {
    ...rest,
    ...addmoreObject,
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Matthew one more quick help how can I give same value in different key i.e oldName will be new key and value will be name

Comment: You can just add `oldName: rest.name` to the object

Answer (score 0):

```js
let objArr = [
    { "name" : "mark", "height" : "tall", "hairColor": "black"},
    { "name" : "ben", "height" : "medium", "color": "fair"},
    { "name" : "neil", "height" : "small", "color": "dark"}
];

let addmoreObject = {"gender": "male", "age": 33};

let newArr = objArr.map(({ hairColor, color, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, ...addmoreObject }));
console.log(newArr);
```